# How to exclude Android Studio's internal m2 repository from our project?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

My organization maintains its own repository of libraries & tools for building projects.  New items are added to this repository only after manual review by an authorized member of the organization.  That means in our android project we remove Maven Central, JCenter, etc. from our gradle build scripts.  The repository maintained by the organization is the only one used to build releases on the build server, and *should* be the only one used by developers to produce dev builds of this project on their own machines.

However, even when the top level buildscript looks like this (note: no repositories):

```
buildscript {
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'
    }
}
allprojects {
}
task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

The project still builds when run from Android Studio, even though it fails (as it should) when invoking gradlew from the terminal.   Apparently Android Studio is still referencing its own built-in repository (located at [Android Install]/gradle/m2repository/).  This leads to the undesirable situation where a developer unwittingly breaks the build because they have been referencing items that are not in the organization's repository, but are in Android Studio's built-in repository.  Rather than try to enforce that everyone executes a gradle build in the terminal prior to every commit, is there a way for the gradle file or project settings to tell Android Studio not to include any repositories that have not been explicitly declared?

Comment: What in the gradle build tools are you trying to avoid using accidentally?

Comment: any libraries or tools that aren't in the org's repo, or are different from the ones in the repo.

Comment: Android Studio isn't in your repo.

Comment: Sorry - is that a question?

Comment: Clearly not. The point is that you&amp;#39;re already trusting non-internal-repo code, and code the IDE relies on also isn't in your internal repo. What's the difference?

Comment: What non-internal repo code are you referring to?  Our repo contains a set of trusted libraries that are sufficient to execute a gradle build with.
 
The difference is that the contents of the repo within the Android Studio installation folder potentially contains files that are not within or did not come from our repo.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155116/discussion-between-duggulous-and-dave-newton).

Comment: The same non-internal repo *you're* referring to and trying to avoid. The tool itself, and its supporting libraries, aren't in the internal repo. Since Android Studio is based on IntelliJ (or at least it was), neither is its source. So you're already trusting external code and libraries. What specific libraries are you trying to avoid?

Comment: Our build server does not use Android Studio, and obviously does not reference the Android Studio cache.  What I'm trying to do is keep Android from making libraries available on the developer's machine that are not available on the build server.

Answer (score 0):

Android Studio doesn't use a built-in repo **for the android plugin** (`com.android.tools.build:gradle`).
Android Studio caches this plugins after downloading them the first time.
It means that in your case the first time is downloaded from a certified repo.

You can find this cache here:

```
file:/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/gradle/m2repository/com/android/tools/build/gradle/
```

Also the new Android plugin 3.3.x is located only in the **google maven repo** "https://maven.google.com" and not in `jcenter`.

Keep in mind the the support libraries, firebase and google play services libraries now are stored **in the same google maven repo**, but the old release are stored offline in **android_sdk/extras/.**

Here you can find more details:
https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies.html#google-maven

Comment: maybe "built-in" is not the right term to use.  We can call it "internal cache" instead if that is more accurate.  Regardless, Android Studio references that repo even though the project does not call for it.  Do you have any suggestions on how to make it not do that for a particular project?

Comment: @duggulous You can't avoid cache, but keep in mind that you have to download a first time from a repo. Then if you use a private repo, the cached version is in any case downloaded from your certified repo.

Comment: Let's consider the case where there are 2 different projects that reference different 2 repos.  Project A references repo A, and does not trust repo B.  Project B references repo B and does not trust repo A.  Can one installation of Android Studio be used to work on both of these projects without each project making its repo available to the other?

Comment: Not so sure about it

Answer (score 0):

> Apparently Android Studio is still referencing its own built-in
>   repository (located at [Android Install]/gradle/m2repository/)

Simply replace those files with your own and edit the maven-metadata.xml to include the correct versions i.e `android-sdks\extras\m2repository\com\android\support\support-v4\27.0.0`
Edit the `maven-metadata.xml` located in `android-sdks\extras\m2repository\com\android\support\support-v4` by adding `<version>27.0.0</version>` in case it was not included ...etc or make a script to automate the process.

If your organization's repository is built like an offline maven repo then it could be already organized that way.

I recently added some support libraries that way and it worked without using google(), jscenter()...etc and the build was successful.